# Creating continuous receiver for session enabled subscription from Azure Bus Topic

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

We are having a session-enabled azure bus topic. This topic can have multiple messages with distinct session IDs. We want to create a listener/receiver that keeps reading messages from the Topic. As we have multiple dynamic session IDs, we can not use `acceptSession` to create a handler. We have tried using the methods `createReceiver` and `acceptNextSession` methods of ServiceBusClient but they have the following issues

1. CreateReceiver: This method does not work on session-enabled subscriptions giving a runtime error.
2. acceptNextSession: This method only listens to the first message and does not read further messages.

Our Current code is :

> 

```
 const serviceBusSettings = this.appSettings.Settings.serviceBus;
 const sbClient = new ServiceBusClient(serviceBusSettings.connectionString);

 //const receiver = sbClient.createReciver(topicName, subscriptionName);
 const receiver = sbClient.acceptNextSession(topicName, subscriptionName);
 const handleTopicError = async (error: any) => {
             this.logger.error(error);
             throw error;
        };

 (await receiver).subscribe({
        processMessage: handleTopicMessage, // handleTopicMessage is a method passed as an argument to the function where this code snippet exists
        processError: handleTopicError
 });
```

We also tried implementation one of the sample code repo wiki. But the methods shared in the example seems to be no longer available in new npm version of @azure/service-bus  [Link to tried example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/7933ac82feb91f27713ca7747c3a426038e988d2/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/javascript/gettingStarted/receiveMessagesStreaming.js#L18)

Can anyone suggest some solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a sample showing how you can continually read through all the available sessions. Could you please check to see if it is helpful?

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/21ff34e2589f255e8ffa7f7d5d65ca40434ec34d/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/v7/javascript/advanced/sessionRoundRobin.js